# Converting values into form

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi following code is retrieving rows values from a gridview.

```
  $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {
                           var Id= $(this).closest('tr').find('.IDName').text();
                           var Company= $(this).closest('tr').find('.FName').text();
```

What I want to do is convert Id and Company into form and submit it to jquery function       $("#form").xxx

Plz Help.

Comment: "convert Id and Company into form " ?????

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
$("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {
    var Id= $(this).closest('tr').find('.IDName').text();
    var Company= $(this).closest('tr').find('.FName').text();

    var newform=document.createElement('FORM');
    newform.name='myForm';
    newform.method='POST';
    newform.action='GIVE_YOUR_ACTION';

    my_tb=document.createElement('INPUT');
    my_tb.type='TEXT';
    my_tb.name='Id';
    my_tb.value=Id;
    newform.appendChild(my_tb);

    my_tb2=document.createElement('INPUT');
    my_tb2.type='TEXT';
    my_tb2.name='Company';
    my_tb2.value=Company;
    newform.appendChild(my_tb2);
    document.body.appendChild(newform);
    newform.submit();

});
```

Comment: Do i need to create this form in html too?

Comment: You don't need to create this in html

Answer (score 0):

You can just submit the values with ajax, without an actual form, like so :

```
$("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {
    var Id= $(this).closest('tr').find('.IDName').text();
    var Company= $(this).closest('tr').find('.FName').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : '/url/to/file.asp',
        data: {Company: Company, Id: Id}
    });
});
```